# Hamburger Menu in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Estoy tratando de hacer que el menú hamburguesa sea siempre visible en la navegación, desactivando el botón atrás, pero el icono del menú no se visualiza.
tengo el icono en la master page.

```
   private static async Task Navigate<T>(T page) where T : Page
    {
       NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(page, false);
       await App.Navigator.PushAsync(page);
    }
```

- Ya he verificado que el icono exista.
- he colocado el icono en
  diferentes paginas(Master, Detail, Home)

Y no logro que el icono del menu hamburgesa sea siempre visible

Comment: Para que el menu hamburguesa se muestre, es necesario que la pila de navegación esté en la misma vista. Si navegas a una nueva vista, lógicamente, verás el botón atrás. Para evitarlo, en lugar de hacer un Push, establece la nueva vista como la vista principal, Es decir: App.MainPage.Detail = MiNuevaVista();

Comment: Pero al establecer el detail, si tienes patrón mvvm como haces que se cargue la viewmodel?